# Pass object to a javascript function using onClick attribute

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp, onclick, modelattribute

I want pass object to a JavaScript function and use objects's attributes. Object contains its attributes. I have tried many methods, but none of the have worked. I have attached the relevant JSP code and java code.

**JSP code**

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="status">

    <input type="checkbox" name="menuDTOs[${status.index}].disable" value="true"
    <c:if test="${item.disable == true}">checked = "checked"</c:if> 
    onClick="checkBoxClick('${item}')"/>

</c:forEach>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
function checkBoxClick(item){
    //Here I want to use attributes
}
```

**Java code**

```
public class MyObject { 

    private Long menuId;
    private String name;
    private Long parentId;
    private String clientId;
    private boolean disable;

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

Any help is welcome,

Thank you very much.